# Access command line arguments in jsf web application backing bean

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, command-line, glassfish

I'm building a web app with jsf 2.3 (Java 8, GlassFish application server). Obviously I dont have access to the main function, so my questions are

1. Can I have access to the command line arguments inside my beans?
2. How can I pass command line arguments to my application through GlassFish?

```
@Named(value = 'myBean')
@ApplicationScope
public class MyBean {

    String argc[] args = ConsoleLineArguments();
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to do that. It's not the model of your application. How about whoever is launching the server creates a configuration file on the local system and your bean code reads that config file? Alternatively, there are also system properties that can be passed to the server startup command.

Comment: I want an argument to determine that the app is running in development mode, localy in my pc. I don't want that configuration be passed to the deployment environment and I don't want to be needed to comment out code before submit an excetutable to my sys admin